# Create a list of Parent and Child items with automatic countdown, OOTB

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I need to create an inventory custom list that has parent and child items.

**For example**, one parent item could be 1000 - Computer and the child items of that item would be something like:

```
1000 - Computer 
1000A - Monitor 
1000B - Tower 
1000C - Keyboard
```

Can this be achieved in SharePoint 2013 and with the same format I've shown above, with out of the box functionality or with SharePoint Designer?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with with automatic countdown, ?!!

Comment: Countdown of parent and child items, like 1000 (parent), 1000A (child), 1000B (child), 1001 (parent) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Using SPD create a workflow that goes and fills in the next ID - https://dlairman.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/add-a-unique-auto-incrementing-column-to-a-sharepoint-list/
2. By creating a custom infopath form for the list. In this you can use Infopath to find the last id and create an expression to generate next id and pass it to the list during submit.

Comment: Thank you but the link isn't responding.

Comment: working fine for me.. check your DNS settings

Comment: Alright finally managed to open the link and the info seems really useful!, Haven't had a chance to try it yet but will report back.